# What's the difference between gnueabi and eabi?

Tags: gcc, arm, clang, eabi

I've seen both arm-linux-gnueabi- and arm-linux-eabi- triplets. From the little I could find it seems gnueabi is a "sub-abi" of eabi. I would like to know what exactly are the differences.

I'm trying to get clang to compile for QNX target, so I'm wondering which abi to use, I tried gnueabi and it worked just fine for a small program.

After inspecting clang's source I see there isn't much difference between the two, except that for "eabi" std::size_t is unsigned long on Darwin, while "gnueabi" always uses unsigned int, independent of OS.

Comment: Someone can name the compiler whatever they like.  So there is no way to know from the name.  Generally, 'eabi' is a bare metal *newlib* version and 'gnueabi' is a Linux glibc version.  At least this is the way `gcc` works; `clang` is generally a different compiler (normally used by llvm)?

Comment: one possible difference might be floating point handling (software vs hardware vs software if hardware fails)